# Materials from Face Mesh not showing up in preview

Tags: spark-ar-studio

I have an issue with a material on a second facemesh not showing in app but they do show up in spark AR. 
I am super new with Spark (As in started today) and I did some face distortion in Blender and created a new Face mesh. This works fine however I also wanted to try creating freckles. I added a new face mesh for that and added a material and custom texture. This shows up in Spark AR but when I try it out in IG and FB only the face distortion and skin smoothing show up. Anyone know what I am doing incorrectly?

I already tried creating a new facemesh, creating a canvas and rectangle and connecting the mesh to that but it does not work.

As the freckles show up in SPARK AR i expect them to show up in app too, but this is not the case.

Comment: Same issue here

Comment: can you post some screenshots?